# How to define an array in const?

Tags: arrays, constants, inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm having some problems defining an array of strings in `const` under the code section in Inno Setup, I have the following:

```pascal
[Code]

const
  listvar: array [0..4] of string =
     ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
```

It's saying I need an `=` where the `:` is, but then I can't define it as an array.

Answer (score 4):

I made a little utility function a little while ago.  It won't allow you to assign an array on a constant but it could do the trick for a variable in a one liner.  Hoping this help.

You can use it this way:

```pascal
listvar := Split('one,two,three,four,five', ',');
```

```pascal
{ ============================================================================ }
{ Split()                                                                      }
{ ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- }
{ Split a string into an array using passed delimeter.                         }
{ ============================================================================ }
Function Split(Expression: String; Separator: String): TArrayOfString;
Var
    i, p : Integer;
    tmpArray : TArrayOfString;
    curString : String;

Begin
    i := 0;
    curString := Expression;

    Repeat
        SetArrayLength(tmpArray, i+1);
        If Pos(Separator,curString) > 0 Then
        Begin
            p := Pos(Separator, curString);
            tmpArray[i] := Copy(curString, 1, p - 1);
            curString := Copy(curString, p + Length(Separator), Length(curString));
            i := i + 1;
        End Else Begin
             tmpArray[i] := curString;
             curString := '';
        End;
    Until Length(curString)=0;

    Result:= tmpArray;
End;
```

Comment: Nice! If you want to support whitespace around the separator, e. g. `'one, two ,  three, four, five '`, you can change the code as follows: `tmpArray[i] := Trim(Copy(curString, 1, p - 1));` and `tmpArray[i] := Trim(curString);`

Answer (score 3):

In Inno Setup 6.2.2, it works like this:

```pascal
procedure Test();
var StringArray: TArrayOfString;
begin
    StringArray := ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using the following solution. It is especially well suited for initializing large arrays (for example, CRC tables) because it preserves the original syntax for data.

```pascal
var
  listvar: array of string;

procedure fill_listvar(var arr: array of string; const data: array of string);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  SetArrayLength(arr, GetArrayLength(data));
  for i := 0 to GetArrayLength(data) - 1 do
    arr[i] := data[i];
end;

procedure Init();
begin
  fill_listvar(listvar, ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']);
end;
```