# How can I get the length of a static array?

Tags: arrays, inno-setup, pascalscript

If I have a static array of labels:

```pascal
Labels: array [0..6] of TLabel;
```

How can I get the number of labels in a procedure?

Also if anyone could tell me more about the kind of Pascal Inno Setup is using, or if there's some manual for it. I can't do `High()` on the array, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Inno Setup Unicode version:***

In Unicode versions of Inno Setup you can use the `Low`, `High` and even `Length` functions like known from Delphi. So maybe it's time to move to the Unicode version to write a code like this:

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  Labels: array [0..6] of TLabel;
begin
  MsgBox(
    'Array length: ' + IntToStr(Length(Labels)) + #13#10 +
    'Array low bound: ' + IntToStr(Low(Labels)) + #13#10 +
    'Array high bound: ' + IntToStr(High(Labels)),
    mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

---

***Inno Setup ANSI version:***

There is no way to get length or bounds of a static array in ANSI versions of the InnoSetup. There are no `Low` nor `High` functions and the `Length` function is applicable only for string, the [`GetArrayLength`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getarraylength.htm) only for dynamic arrays. Just [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10177531/960757) static array Inno Setup nitpick.

Source:
[http://www.mirality.co.nz](http://www.mirality.co.nz/inno/tips.php#arrays)

Comment: That doesn't work it says invalid proc. I think that's only for variable length arrays.

Comment: Sadly this looks like the right answer. I am working around it by using the preprocessor to hold the high variable and then declaring like `Labels: array [0..{#testing}] of TLabel;`. I will update my question and mark this answer as correct after one day if nobody else has a better idea.

Comment: `High(Labels)`, `Low(Labels)` work here (Inno Setup 5.4.2) ([RemObjects link](http://code.remobjects.com/p/pascalscript/source/commit/21/)).

Comment: @Sertac, then they must change it to the 5.4.3 version, since my 5.4.3 compiler fails with `Unknown identifier`. Also the help file has no mention about `High` nor `Low` functions.

Comment: @TLama - Weird.. it doesn't make much sense. The commit I linked is dated 2007-01-19, the document you linked is dated 2006-07-09 (high-low didn't exist then). Also it doesn't need to be documented, it is not a feature of Inno Setup, like f.i. `Inc()`. I'd rather think it to be a bug probably with the version of pascal script linked with 5.4.3.

Comment: @Sertac, so then is probably something wrong on my side. I've just installed [`InnoSetup 5.4.2 ANSI`](http://files.jrsoftware.org/is/5/isetup-5.4.2.exe) version and I'm getting the same `Unknown identifier` for `High` and `Low`.

Comment: @TLama - Interesting.. I was using the unicode version. Now I installed 5.4.3 unicode and High/Low works ok.

Comment: @Sertac, that's it! The Unicode version has the `High` and `Low` whilst ANSI not.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as correct, TLama. I am sticking with ANSI for now.. I don't know all the implications of changing over. I ended up using the preprocessor to define a constant which I use to declare the high end of the array and then later when I need it I use the constant in code as well.